# Wrong format for Google client_secret.json file

Tags: python, google-oauth, gmail-api

I could use some help with creating the `client_secret.json` file I need to access my Gmail API.
I have followed step by step the instructions from the Python quickstart for GMail API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

But the JSON file that I downloaded from "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs." section in the API & Services Credentials does not follow the expected format:

Based on comments found in the google-api-python-client module I'm using, my downloaded JSON file should follow the format described here:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/client-secrets.md

But my file does not contain any 'web' or 'installed' entries. Instead, it looks like this:

```
{
"WCc":{
    "client_id":"XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id":"my_project_name",
    "Anc":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "hVc":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "znc":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "s2a":"XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "oNc":["http://localhost"]
    }
}
```

I must have missed something in the quickstart instructions but can't figure out what. I have Googled for similar JSON file formats but couldn't find anyone with this kind of file having a similar problem...
Can someone help me out?
Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:** I did create a "Desktop App" In Application type. Walkthrough:
[image: Create credential]
[image: Application type is Desktop App]
[image: Created credentials are not correct]

**EDIT #2:**
I have managed to work around the issue but copying the structure of a "correct" json file and just replacing the client_id and client_secret fields with the values from my "incorrect" json file. It works, but I'm looking for a fully automated process here so my problem is not solved

Answer (score 1):

The QuickStart tells you to create  [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#authorize_credentials_for_a_desktop_application)

- Click Application type > Desktop app.

Installed app credentials start with the word installed

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "[REDACTED]",
    "project_id": "daimto-tutorials-101",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "[REDACTED]",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "http://localhost"
    ]
  }
}
```

Go back to google cloud console and create the proper credential type.

Comment: I've edited my post: I followed the quickstart and did create a credential for a "Desktop App" When asked for the application type (see screenshots)
Following these steps I'm getting a json file formated as I described in my initial post.
I have managed to work around the issue but copying the structure of a "correct" json file and just replacing the client_id and client_secret fields with the values from my "incorrect" json file. It works, but I'm looking for a fully automated process here so my problem is not solved

Comment: Okay you win let me send a really fast email to the team.  That's broken.

Comment: The team is looking into it now.  I will let you know when i hear back.

Comment: I just heard from the team its fixed.  I checked myself the credential files are now generating in the proper format.  Thanks for reporting the issue.

Comment: :D Nice! Thanks a lot Linda!

Comment: NP happy coding.

Comment: Please accept this answer so that i can duplicate others to it.

Comment: I can confirm that I saw this issue yesterday and it is solved today. I would like to get the internal docs for that format. Can you PM a contact so I can ask?

Comment: For which format the correct one or the broken one?   I don't think either are documented but i can ask at my meeting with them next week.

Comment: The file format from this answer is missing a refresh token as per the google libraries