# Expected a JSON object with a single property for a "web" or "installed" application

Tags: php, google-analytics, gcloud

When I try to authenticate gcloud  default login with application_default_credentials.json.We are getting unexpected file format error. Can you please suggest what this error means

```
gcloud auth application-default login \
-- 

scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly \
--client-id-file=/home/bitnami/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
```

ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.login) Invalid file format. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets Expected a JSON object with a single property for a "web" or "installed" application

Comment: This is a duplicate question,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/76967972/1841839   This is a bug that was fixed yesterday by google delete your credentials.json and download a new one there was an issue with how it was created

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo - Post an answer to this question so that it can be accepted. There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76969296/8016720) on this issue.

Comment: @JohnHanley if you see any others just dupe them to the original issue.